# NSData writeToFile writes Plist successfully, but then crashes, giving NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization, plist

I am converting a JSON file to a plist using the new NSJSONSerialization class and NSPropertyListSerialization class. I manage to convert my JSON to a Plist without errors, but then, at my last step, when I go to write the plist to my desktop, the program crashes, but AFTER the Plist has been generated!

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path]; \\(NSURL *)path -->goes to my JSON file
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                              error:nil];

//the following removes all key/object pairs where the object is null, because NSPropertyListSerialization with throw an error if there are null values
for (id __strong object in [json objectForKey:@"terms"]) {
        if ([object objectForKey:@"image"] == [NSNull null]) {
            [object removeObjectForKey:@"image"];
        }
    }

 //the following NSPropertyListSerialization method returns an NSData
 id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:(id)json 
                                                       format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 
                                             errorDescription:nil]; 


NSError *writeToFileError;
[plist writeToFile:@"/Users/kalaracey/Desktop/test.plist" 
        atomically:YES 
          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
             error:&writeToFileError];
```

Then, at this last line, an `NSInvalidArgumentException` is thrown, and crashes my program. However, the plist was successfully generated! I can read it, and all is well, except my program crashes.

Could someone please explain why this crashes, and how I could avoid crashing?

Comment: The exception is an `NSInvalidArgumentException` for the last method - i.e., plist (supposedly) does not respond to `writeToFile:atomicallyencoding:error:` See below how Mundi fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the variable `plist` is type `id`. Cast it to `NSData` and you should be fine.

```
NSData *plist = (NSData *) [NSPropertyListSerialization ...];
```

As you correctly point out in the comment, `NSData` should use the `writeToFile:atomically:` method.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. `NSData` does not respond to `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error`. That is an `NSDictionary `method. The `NSData` method is just `writeToFile:atomically:`. Am I supposed to delete the question if I have just answered it?

Comment: No, just check the tick mark above (below the number). I will adapt my answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: Ok. But I don't have to change the return type of plist for it to still work. Is there a reason that I should? In the developer documentation, it says to give the object that is returned by NSPropertyListSerialization a type of id. They don't explicitly say that, but it's in the example that way.

Comment: If you show me the link to the example I might be able to tell you what's different, if you still want to pursue it.