# Adding Image to plist

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, plist

I'm making an app where I take picture using camera and want to save those picture on plist so that i can use in future. I also want to retrive the saved images from plist and display them on imageview. There are multiple images.Please anyone can help me with this

Here is my code which I'm using for adding to plist

```
imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageView.image]];

[imageArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

But when I'm trying to retrive image and set it on imageview I cant see image.
Thanks.

Comment: Why plist ?? Cant you save them in your sandbox ?

Comment: If you want to save in plist, convert the image to nsdata and try..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9758915/344798

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846620/ios-load-image-from-plist-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save like this method to plist. The supported format  are NSData, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, and NSNumber. You can convert your UIImage into NSData and can write in plist.

To convert an image into NSData

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageview.image);
[imageArray addObject:data];
[imageArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

and also NSLog your file path to find where yoyr plist is saved.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

see this one ,

For saving :

```
- (IBAction)saveImage {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is my image from camera
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
}
```

For retrieving:

```
- (IBAction)getImage {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
}
```